# javafx accordion changelistener

Tags: java, javafx

In javafx scenebuilder, I have created accordion. In the netbeans, I would like to add changelistener to the titledpane in the accordion.  I want to display a message on clicking the titledpane. How can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display a message when someone clicked on titledpane ,just implement on mouse click event of TitiledPane

[image]

In Controller class implement that method

```
  @FXML
    private void TitledPaneClick(MouseEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Mouse clicked");
    }
```

Comment: This should work. I can see hash symbol in front of the onmouse clicked text field in your screenshot.But I am not able to find hash symbol in front of the textfield in my scenebuilder. So when i run the controller code without that it's saying page language error. can you tell me how can I get the hash symbol in front of the textfield.

Comment: download latest build of scene builder , i am currently using Version: 1.1-b18

Answer (score 0):

And also I tried this way to get it.

```
EventHandler<MouseEvent> mousehandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        System.out.println("hi");}
};
titledpaneName.setOnMouseClicked(mousehandler);
```

titledpaneName is the name of the titled pane in the accordion.
The code above prints hi on clicking the titledpane in accordion.